# Technique to remove any properties an excel file phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a file i would like to compress or remove any type of formatting in excel 2007. My file size is 450kb but when I export all the worksheets in a new workbook the size is now 104kb. Is there a way in phpexcel to compress the file or just eport the worksheets in a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

If you have such problems with the size of the files generated by PHPExcel, then you would probably be best off looking at an alternative solution that uses MS Excel itself, such as COM